# TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, yield, yield-return

I have written a generating function that should return a dictionary. however when I try to print a field I get the following error

```
print row2['SearchDate']
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is my code

```
from csv import DictReader
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def genSearch(SearchInfo):
    for row2 in DictReader(open(SearchInfo)):
        yield row2

train = 'minitrain.csv'

SearchInfo = 'SearchInfo.csv'

row2 = {'SearchID': -1}

for row1 in DictReader(open(train)):
    if 'SearchID' in row1 and 'SearchID' in row2 and row1['SearchID'] == row2['SearchID']:
        x = deepcopy( row1 )
        #x['SearchDate'] = row2['percent']
        x.update(row2)    
        print 'new'
        print x
    else: 
        #call your generator
        row2 = genSearch(SearchInfo)
        print row2['SearchDate']
```

Comment: What did you expect `row2` to contain; the first row from the `DictReader()`?

Comment: yes @MartijinPieters

Comment: Calling a generator function produces the generator object, not the next value from that generator. Create the generator once, store it somewhere, then use that generator to produce values (as hspandher shows in their answer).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Generator returns an iterator, you explicitly needs to call next on it.

Your last line of code should be something like -

```
rows_generator = genSearch(SearchInfo)
row2 = next(rows_generator, None)
print row2['SearchDate']
```

Ideally, we use iterators in a loop, which automatically does the same for us.

Answer (score 13):

Generators are necessarily **iterators** , not **iterables**. Iterables contain
 `__item__()` and `__getitem__()` methods, whilst iterators contain `next()` / `__next__()` method (python version 2.x/3.x).