# Python 2.7: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, iteration, export-to-csv

I've built a script that crawls court listings in the UK, generates a list of links to each court's address page, and then want to scrape the address from said page.

It works pretty well so far but I am stuck at the "write to csv" bit. I think it's got to do with the `iteritems()`'s lack of `get` method, based on a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844089/typeerror-generator-object-has-no-attribute-getitem). I get that an **iterator** doesn't have the same methods as an **iterable** (I am using an iterator in my code), but it didn't help me solve my particular problem.

Here's my code:

```
import csv
import time
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# lambda expression to request url and parse it through bs
soup = lambda url: bs((requests.get(url)).text, "html.parser")


def crawl_court_listings(base, buff, char):
    """  """
    # common URL segment + cuffer URL segment + end character -> URL
    url = base + buff + str(chr(char))

    # soup lambda expression -> grab first unordered list
    links = (soup(url)).find('div', {'class', 'content inner cf'}).find('ul')

    # empty dictionary
    results = {}

    # loop through links, get link title and href
    for item in links.find_all('a', href=True):
        court_link = item['href']
        title = item.string

        # generate full court address page url from href
        full_court_link = base + court_link

        # save title and full URL to results
        results[title] = full_court_link

        # increment char var by 1
        char += 1

    # return results dict and incremented char value
    return results, char


def get_court_address(court_name, full_court_link):
    """ """

    # get horrible chunk of poorly formatted address(es)
    address_blob = (soup(full_court_link)).find('div', {'id': 'addresses'}).text

    # clean the blob
    clean_address = ("\n".join(line.strip() for line in address_blob.split("\n")))

    # write to csv
    with open('court_addresses.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = [court_name, full_court_link, clean_address]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow(fieldnames)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    base = 'https://courttribunalfinder.service.gov.uk/'
    buff = 'courts/'

    # 65 = "A". Starting from Char "A", retrieve list of Titles and Links of for Court Addresses. Return Char +1
    results, char = crawl_court_listings(base, buff, 65)

    # 90 = "Z". Until Z, pass title and list from results into get_court_address(), then wait a few seconds
    while char <= 90:
        for t, l in results.iteritems():
            get_court_address(t, l)
            time.sleep(random.randint(0,5))
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\CourtScraper.py", line 63, in <module>
    get_court_address(t, l)
  File ".\CourtScraper.py", line 49, in get_court_address
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "c:\python27\Lib\csv.py", line 149, in _dict_to_list
    return [rowdict.get(key, self.restval) for key in self.fieldnames]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Even though I get an error, it produces the csv file with cells A1 and A2 populated with `title` and `full-court_link`, but no `address`. The address (when printed) looks like this:

```
Write to us:


1st Floor

Piccadilly Exchange

Piccadilly Plaza

Manchester

Greater Manchester

M1 4AH
```

So my first thoughts were that I was trying to write multi-line text into a single cell which was causing the error, but not really sure how to confirm that. I used `print(type(address))` which came back as `unicode` and not a `list`, so I don't think that's causing the issue. I don't understand where it's getting the `list` the issue relates to from, if that makes sense.

If it is the `iteritems()` method causing the issue, how do I go about resolving it?

Can someone explain the error and point me in the direction of solving it please?

Comment: Why are you using DictWriter when you have a list rather than a dict?

Comment: your issues is you're using csv.DictWriter wrong - this line `csv.writerow(fieldname)` in particular. the input of `.writerow()` has to be a `dict` not a list [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row you are writing, you need to pass in a *dictionary* - you are passing in the header list

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

```
# write to csv
with open('court_addresses.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = [court_name, full_court_link, clean_address]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^  This should be a dict
```

The dict needs to look like::

> {'court_name': X, 'full_court_link': Y, 'clean_address': Z}

HTH

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
writer.writerow(fieldnames)
```

"fieldnames" is a **list** of field names.  You need to pass a **dict** of key-value pairs.   So it should look more like this:

```
# write to csv
with open('court_addresses.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    # note - these are strings, not variables
    fieldnames = ['court_name', 'full_court_link', 'clean_address']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow({"court_name" : court_name,
                     "full_court_link" : full_court_link},
                     "clean_address" : clean_address})
```

PSST:  you have another issue. You are re-opening your output file for every court that you parse.  You probably want to open that file once (under __main__) and then pass the handle into get_court_address()

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on opening once under main, that's really useful

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('court_addresses.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['court_name', 'full_court_link', 'clean_address']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow({'court_name': court_name, 'full_court_link': full_court_link, 'clean_address': clean_address})
```